# StreamBuilder snapshot has no data Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I took a look at some similar questions but I didn't find what I'm looking for.
I have a `StreamBuilder` whose snapshot has no data but if I look inside the collection that it's listening I can see that there are 2 documents.

This is my first time using `StreamBuilder` so maybe I'm missing some basics rules.
I say that it `has no data` because it's always displayed `"No chats here"`.

This is the code (stream function later) :

```
StreamBuilder<ChatCard>(
        stream: widget.database.streamChats(widget.user),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Container(
              child: Text(
                "There's something here!",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Container(
              child: Text(
                "No chats here",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
```

This is the stream function, there are some extra checks because I'm trying to figure it out what isn't working, by the way seems no error in `try` block and no `if` statements violated:

```
Stream<ChatCard> streamChats(MyUser sender) {
    if (sender != null) {
      if (sender.id != null) {
        try {
          FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("ids/tabs/${sender[0].toLowerCase()}/${sender.toLowerCase()}/chats")
              .snapshots();
          print(
              "ids/tabs/${sender[0].toLowerCase()}/${sender.toLowerCase()}/chats'");
        } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
          print(e);
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
      } else
        print("Sender ID null");
    } else
      print("Sender null");
  }
```

If you can also provide me some informations about `StreamBuilder` and `Stream`in general, I would be very happy to listen but obviously this is a plus.

Comment: what do you see if you call `print(snapshot);` before `if (snapshot.hasData) {`?

Comment: `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("${sender.id}/chats'")` Is this suppose to be how you construct collectionReference to a `chats` subcollection?

Comment: @pskink I see : flutter: AsyncSnapshot<ChatCard>(ConnectionState.none, null, null, null)

Comment: `ConnectionState.none` and nothing else? if so then `widget.database.streamChats(widget.user)` does not emit any data

Comment: @pskink No, only what I wrote before, none and some null fields

Comment: so it seems that `widget.database.streamChats(widget.user)` does not emit any data - it is an empty `Stream`

Comment: @SimonSot yes each ID has a sub collection called  "chats"

Comment: @pskink ok but how is this possible? I'm sure the path is right...Maybe database rules?

Comment: @federicoD'Armini collection reference is invalid then. Here is your mistake

Comment: @SimonSot what does it means "Is invalid"? Can you provide more informations please, I'm sure the path is right or maybe I'm missing something outside path...

Comment: `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("collectionName").doc("docname"). collection("subcollectionName")` this is a collectionReference to subcollection

Comment: No wait you're right this is the old path I forgot to update it...This is the right one I'll edit the post.
Right path : 'ids/tabs/${sender[0].toLowerCase()}/${sender.toLowerCase()}/chats';

Comment: @SimonSot as above now it points to a valid collection, I forgot to update the code here but my problem is on this path

Comment: @federicoD'Armini still you have to construct path via dot notation like i wrote to you in a comment. Not with slashes, in native development you can pass to `getPath()` string like that but in flutter it is yet to be done. So rewrite it please and try again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230766/discussion-between-federico-darmini-and-simon-sot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, the problem was the Stream, I wasn't returning the right one but with `QuerySnapshot` it works :

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> streamChats(User sender) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("ids")
        .doc("tabs")
        .collection(sender.id[0].toLowerCase())
        .doc(sender.id[0].toLowerCase())
        .collection("chats")
        .snapshots();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `ChatCard` objects from your stream, , assuming you want them in a list, because you are getting a list of `docs`, and return them.

```
Stream<List<ChatCard>> streamChats(MyUser sender) {
List<ChatCard> chatCardList=[];

    if (sender != null) {
      if (sender.id != null) {
        try {
         return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("${sender.id}/chats'")
              .snapshots().then((snap){
           for(var item in snap.data.docs){
             chatCardList.add(ChatCard.fromMap(snap.data));}
          return chatCardList; });
          print(
              "${sender.id}/chats'");
        } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
          print(e);
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
      } else
        print("Sender ID null");
    } else
      print("Sender null");
  }
```

Comment: Yes I'll do this later but as pskink told above my stream does not emit any data...Maybe this is the main issue